# Why is my rust shell output littered with format characters?

Tags: rust, zsh, iterm2, rustup

When I use rust commands `rustup` or `cargo` my output is littered with what appear to be output format markup characters: `$<2>`

```
$<2>info: $<2>syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin'
$<2>info: $<2>latest update on 2023-02-09, rust version 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07)
$<2>info: $<2>downloading component 'cargo'
$<2>info: $<2>downloading component 'clippy'
$<2>info: $<2>downloading component 'rust-docs'
 19.4 MiB /  19.4 MiB (100 %)   8.8 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
$<2>info: $<2>downloading component 'rust-std'
 27.9 MiB /  27.9 MiB (100 %)   9.1 MiB/s in  3s ETA:  0s
$<2>info: $<2>downloading component 'rustc'
 56.6 MiB /  56.6 MiB (100 %)   9.5 MiB/s in  6s ETA:  0s
$<2>info: $<2>downloading component 'rustfmt'
$<2>info: $<2>installing component 'cargo'
$<2>info: $<2>installing component 'clippy'
$<2>info: $<2>installing component 'rust-docs'
 19.4 MiB /  19.4 MiB (100 %)   3.7 MiB/s in  3s ETA:  0s
$<2>info: $<2>installing component 'rust-std'
 27.9 MiB /  27.9 MiB (100 %)  14.4 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
$<2>info: $<2>installing component 'rustc'
 56.6 MiB /  56.6 MiB (100 %)  17.4 MiB/s in
```

I am on `zsh` on iterm2

on
`Darwin kevs-mbp-3.lan 21.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.5.0: Tue Apr 26 21:08:29 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.121.3~4/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64`

Why ?

Update:

```
% echo $TERM
vt100
% echo $COLORTERM
truecolor
```

Comment: Does this happen on other programs as well? That's really weird, I've never seen that before ... I don't even recognize the `$<2>`, it's not a markup character I know.

Comment: Probably colorization, I’m not sure

Comment: Did you try with a different shell or different terminal? What's the value of your `TERM` and `COLORTERM` environment variables? The part enclosed in `$<2>` should be shown in bold, but I've got no idea what kind of markup this is.

Comment: @Finomnis literally only happens with rust cli tools

Comment: @Miiao I guess so, but to my knowledge these are not [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) as used in most terminals.

Comment: @SvenMarnach added TERM and COLORTERM output

Comment: @kevzettler You should set `TERM` to `xterm-256color`. I still don't know what's going on here, but at least this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to reproduce this by changing my emulation mode from `xterm-256color` to `vt100`.

In iterm2, under Preferences > Profiles > Terminal, update **Report terminal type** from `vt100` to `xterm-256color`. You will have to open a new terminal for this to take effect.

[image: Difference between vt100 and xterm-256colour]